# SQL Server 2012 Express Compatibility Level 100 option not available

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012-express

I need to make my SQL Server 2012 Express compatible with SQL Server 2008 (data types). I found instructions to set compatibility level to 100 to solve my problem.

However, I do not have the option to select level 100.

My current options are:

```
SQL Server 7.0 (70)
SQL Server 2000 (80)
SQL Server 2005 (90)
```

How do I resolve this so that I can set compatibility level to 100?

Comment: If those are your options then you're not running SQL Server 2012, you're running SQL Server 2005. 70 stopped being available as an option since  SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

Using `Alter Database` u change the `COMPATIBILITY LEVEL` of `SQL SERVER`

Try this. (source : **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx)**)

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name 
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = { 90 | 100 | 110 | 120 }
```